# how can I configure RedisHttpSessionConfigure to fallback if redis is not online

Tags: spring, redis, spring-session

I'm using spring-session + redis as documented here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/httpsession-xml.html

How can I configure RedisHttpSessionConfigure such that for local development, redis is not needed and the application will simply default to the container session handling?

Answer (score 1):

Generally this isn't recommended because you are differing your development environment from your production environment. It should be quite trivial to point your dev machine to a Redis instance.

If you need to support it, you can use [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-xml). For example, with XML you can use something like:

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <bean id="springSessionRepositoryFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="production">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"/>
</beans>
```

The key is to ensure that your dev environment also has a Bean that implements Filter named `springSessionRepositoryFilter`. In this example, I used `CharacterEncodingFilter` which should do nothing since the encoding property is not set but feel free to replace with whatever you like.

The next thing you will need to do is [activate your environments](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-enable). For example, you can use

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="production"
```

Comment: I'm looking to configure a backup session store in production if redis goes offline for some reason. How can I do that in spring boot? I'm running 3 instances of service in docker and using redis as session store. I do not want application to fail and use guavava or container default session store if redis goes down for some reason or if not available during start up.